# Looking for good load testing tools to test my web GIS

Tags: arcgis-server, performance

I am looking for good load testing tools to test my web GIS which runs on Apache/ESRI AU's Dekho application (Flash based, so would require AMF support within the load testing tool).

I am currently working SoapUI/LoadUI, but I am having a tough time creating steps for it, as there are numerous AMF calls from the client to the server. Some calls even have multiple calls embedded into it.

Has anyone used any load testing tool with GIS?

Comment: http://dekhoforum.com/ says "from 1 June 2015, Dekho will not be developed beyond version 4.1.10. Standard support for Dekho however, will continue to be available until 31 August 2016. "

Answer (score 3):

I've had good results with the [Neoload](http://www.neotys.com/product/overview-neoload.html) product made by [Neotys](http://www.neotys.com/).

I used it along with the [Fiddler autorespond](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp) feature to isolate performance issues - the autorespond can respond instantly, which can help determine if it's your code running slowly or if you are just waiting for a third party server to respond.